# Why there is try-catch block in QThread?

Tags: qt

Why there is

```
try
{
    ...
catch (...) {
    qTerminate();
}
```

in Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\Src\qtbase\src\corelib\thread\qthread_unix.cpp ?

1) Is there some logic behind this? With this try-catch block we loose the call stack (backtrace) if an unhandled exception is thrown.

2) Did anyone compile QT with QT_NO_EXCEPTIONS?

Comment: Historically Qt doesn't use exceptions internally and is not fully exception safe for client code, refer to [this doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html) for more details. It's better to just not use exceptions along with Qt - or make sure you catch every possible exception your code might throw yourself, before the exception reaches Qt's internals. The code you are seeing is Qt's response to catching the exception from client code - it doesn't have anything better to do at this point than to terminate the executing program immediately.

Comment: Why do they worry about the program termination? I am not sure about all the platforms, but on Windows and Android, for example, the program is automatically terminated (with std::terminate() as far as I remember) if an unhandled exception is thrown by any thread. Is not it?

Comment: Well, I don't know the exact reasoning of Qt developers but I as a developer using Qt would be grateful to Qt or, in fact, to any other framework or library which would terminate as close to the exception source as possible, not a several dozens of stack frames farther after stack unwinding managed to break some library internals on its way out.

Comment: I would say terminate exactly at the line of code that has thrown an unhandled exception to let runtime library or operating system to create the crash dump with full call stack.

Comment: C++ exceptions may not necessarily terminate an application. Usually, there should be `catch`es to handle the exception in the appropriate function. Un-catched exceptions which "fall" out of `main()` are catched by the compiler-generated code (which calls `main()`) and then the application will be aborted/terminated. IMHO, this is somehow a "point of no return" solution. The better way is that code which `throw`s should `catch` as well except in cases when there is no better handling than just terminating. In short: IMHO, there is nothing wrong with the `qTerminate()`.

Comment: ...and if you don't like it - why don't you wrap your thread function code in a `try { /* thread function body */ } catch (...) { abort(); }` to get better diagnostics for unexpected exceptions?

Comment: what diagnostics you can do with this?