# How To Debug The Threw Exceptions From QThread?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, qthread

Consider the following code<sub>(The system specification is mentioned down below)</sub>:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>

void f()
{
  throw std::runtime_error("Something");
}
int main()
{
  std::thread thr(f);
  thr.join();
}
```

I easily could run it with a debugger and have the stack trace from where the exception threw. Like this:
[image]

But the same code fails if I use a `QThread` instead of `std::thread`:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>

void f()
{
  throw std::runtime_error("Something");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  auto const thr = QThread::create(f);
  thr->start();

  return QCoreApplication::exec();
}
```

Like this:
[image]

It's possible to debug it like `std::thread`? and have the stack frames from where the exception threw?

---

Environment:

- **OS**: Fedora 35
- **Kernel**: Linux 5.15.10
- **Compiler**: GCC 11.2.1
- **Qt**: 5.15.2
- **QtCreator**: 6.0.1

Comment: FYI: [Qt: QThread Error Handling](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29644-QThread-Error-Handling)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874812/why-there-is-try-catch-block-in-qthread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835728/how-to-break-when-a-specific-exception-type-is-thrown-in-gdb